# BaseHead vs Soundminer

Tags: search, engine

Hello all,

so deciding on what to buy, i think soundminer is more of a industry standart? The thing is i would like to add metadata to my own recordings, to make clean libraries, also i need good search tool. Also soundminer different versions got my head spinning(why should i pay for "hd plus universal" version almost 2x amount of money), i really don't understand whats the big difference in them. So what would you choose and why, maybe there are things i should know about both of them?

So far BaseHead wins for the price, but maybe i'm doing a mistake?

thanks for your time and answers :)

Comment: You should also add Iced Audio AudioFinder to the list. However, I haven't used it (nor Basehead either), but I think it's worth a look at considering it's price point.

Comment: as far as i can see its Mac only, so not good for me, thou it looks cool, and the price is good.

Comment: I too became extremely confused by soundminers website and the differences in the versions!  I haven't been on the site in a while but I remember being able to find a comparison chart on there somewhere but I think I had to dig a little to get there

Answer (score 2):

Well one of the features of Basehead http://www.baseheadinc.com/products/basehead-mac/feature-overview is that it actually improves your sex life.  I'm not sure how other products compete with that but its definitely worth checkin in to.

Answer (score 1):

There's pro's and cons to both Basehead and Soundminer HD, so why don't you try out the demo's for both of them and see which one you like best? I personally like Soundminer HD a bit better for how it groups and organises search results, but like you pointed out it's more expensive and you have to pay double to go cross-platform. I only tried the Basehead demo for a couple of weeks about a year ago, and it's certainly a good program, and lots of people swear by it. I think I got confused by how it wouldn't smoothly let me search by categories or library names, but maybe I was just being an idiot or it has been improved since. Try it out for yourself!

Comment: ohh, how stupid of me...somehow i didn't thought that there are demos, downloading now, thanks Daan ;)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've been a big fan of Soundminer - used it since v3 and always have liked it.  Although it is worth bearing in mind that the price of HD/HD+ versus the older versions is dramatically cheaper (read: $600-700 for SMXP and $800 for SMv4 Standard) so I think the price point difference is somewhat negligible nowadays since HD/HD+ have almost all features that SMv4 Standard and SMXP have at half the price (right now the only two major outstanding features are the Admin panel and playlisting a la v4 stye).

For my the choice is uniformity and I like how it works in my workflow.  Everyone I've worked with uses Soundminer, so I like having the comfort in knowing embedded metadata will populate on pretty much any system I have to work on (especially when custom FX are traded for work purposes like FX pulls - it's nice to receive those files and have per-prepared SM metadata).  And I'm just used to how the tools work and the way the Boolean searches work within Soundminer.  I guess it's a personal taste in the choice and when I saw Baseheads layout a while back it's design looked clunky and wasn't pleasing on my eyes (I know, somewhat superfluous, but when you have to stare at a certain piece of software for many hours of the day, I like to choose something that's comfortable for my eyes).

Answer (score 0):

I havent used basehead for several years because Nuendo's built in search is fine.  Before that I was a basehead fan (for a while steve was using a quote from me on his site).  I used it for years.  I have spent very little time on sound miner, so I cant speak to it.

FOr a search and retrieval system basehead was awesome.  I know some people like to do fancy things with their search engine (like applying fx and pitching).  That's not how i work.  Basehead was great, and support was great as well.

dr

Answer (score 0):

+1 for AudioFinder, that's what we use in our facility.